# In mysql how to insert a column with huge data contained in table with no downtime

Tags: mysql

If a table in MySQL containing suppose 1 million record, how can I add a column at any position with no downtime expected.

Comment: You cannot expect this.

Comment: @Drew it was being asked in an interview, and as per interviewer its possible. So I am curious to know how to achieve

Comment: Ok, the interviewer walks on water and is never wrong. All db commands issued at his/her discretion are instantaneously fulfilled with no downtime. I cannot compete with that parallel universe. So, I will stay in this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's ALTER TABLE performance can become very frustrating with very large tables. **ALTER** statements makes a new temporary table, copies records from your existing table into the new table even if the data wouldn't strictly need to be copied, and then replaces the old table with the new table.

Suppose you have a table with one million records and if you try to add 3 columns in it, then it will certainly copy the table 3 times, which means coping 3 million records.

A faster way of adding columns is to create your own new table, then **select** all of the rows from the existing table into it. You can create the structure from the existing table, then modify the structure however you’d like, then select in the data. Make sure that you **select** the information into the new table in the same order as the fields are defined.

```
 1. CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE table
 2. INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM table
 3. RENAME TABLE table = old_table, table = new_table;
```

If you have foreign key constraints you can handle these foreign keys using

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```